# TV show episode about a spirit ripping out organs

Tags: story-identification, tv, supernatural, ghost

I remember watching an episode of what I think was a TV show. I think it may have been *Supernatural*, but I do not know for sure.

The episode was about several people dying due to having had some vital organ ripped out of their bodies. The protagonists, I think it was two men, figure out that these people had organs transplanted from a deceased woman, whose spirit is now ripping said organs out of the recipients.

The two protagonists meet a woman who received an organ, I think it may have been a kidney, and discuss the situation. They reckon that they would be able to use hoodoo to prevent the woman from dying due to the spirit. The woman asks "Voodoo?", to which the protagonists reply that no, they are talking about hoodoo. Just as they are discussing all of this, the woman grabs her abdomen and collapses, having been afflicted by the spirit just as everyone before.

Is that from *Supernatural*? If so, which episode?

Comment: Looking at the two answers -- different episodes of the same series, each with some parts that match the question and some that do not -- I wonder if the question is conflating the two episodes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe you're referring the Season 6 *Supernatural* episode, "[Mannequin 3: The Reckoning](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1627711/)".

To clarify some details of the plot mentioned in your description, the ghost, Rose Brown, didn't rip out any organs, nor did most of her victims receive any organ transplants from her. She was just killing various men who'd bullied her and unintentionally caused her death.

The only victim who had received an organ from her (a kidney, as you said) was her sister, Isabel, and Rose didn't mean to kill her; it happened inadvertently while she was attempting to run Dean over with a car.

Here's the relevant portion of the episode synopsis from [the *Supernatural* Wiki page](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/6.14_Mannequin_3:_The_Reckoning):

> In Passaic, Sam speaks to Isabel Brown. She describes her sister, Rose, as quiet and shy - the sort of girl who was an easy target for teasing and pranks. Leafing through a photo album, Sam realizes that the janitor from Paterson also used to work at Salzman & Sons. Back at the factory, Sam interviews workers, and one in particular—Johnny—seems very nervous. That night, Johnny is attacked, but Sam is there to intervene. **He confesses to Sam that he and some workmates bullied Rose by leading her to believe she had a secret admirer. When she arrived at an apartment for a supposed date, they revealed the prank, and, as she went to leave, Steve grabbed her and she fell, hitting her head on a coffee table and dying.**
>
> Sam finds out where they buried the body and heads off to salt and burn Rose's corpse. He calls Johnny, telling him the haunting is over, but he is mistaken. That night Johnny returns to his apartment and explains to his Real Doll that he is going to leave town, but she becomes animated by Rose's ghost and kills him.
>
> **At a loss, Sam speaks to Isabel, and she reveals that she had one of Rose's kidneys transplanted into her when she was 16. As a result, Rose's spirit can move around, able to go wherever Isabel does.** Sam drives Isabel to meet with Dean, and the brothers try to figure out a way to put Rose's spirit to rest. **Sam suggests Hoodoo as a temporary solution, but, as they discuss the option, the Impala revs up. Rose has possessed the Impala, and she tries to run Dean over. He manages to maneuver it into a wall, but Isabel is fatally injured in the resulting crash.** As she dies, the spirit of Rose appears and apologizes before disappearing in flames.

And here's a [transcript](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/6.14_Mannequin_3:_The_Reckoning_(Transcript)) of the conversation you mentioned between the two male protagonists:

> SAM: No. **I think we have to go hoodoo.**
>
> DEAN: Hoodoo?
>
> SAM: Yeah, hoodoo.
>
> DEAN: That's more of a band-aid, not really a cure.
>
> SAM: It buys us a minute.
>
> DEAN: All right, Louisiana it is.
>
> ISABEL: **Voodoo?! What the hell are you talking about?**
>
> DEAN: **Actually, it's "hoodoo." It's a little different.**
>
> <sub>*Supernatural* - S06E14 - "Mannequin 3: The Reckoning"</sub>

A clip of that scene is also up on YouTube:

Comment: Yeah, that is the scene that I was remembering. Seems like I misremembered parts of the plot, but that certainly seems like the scene, and the dialogue fits.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds somewhat like the *Supernatural* episode "[Heartache](https://supernatural.fandom.com/wiki/Heartache)."

From the episode description at the linked page:

> Sam and Dean investigate a string of unusual murders where the victims were all recipients of organs from the same donor. The killer is captured, but things become even more complicated when the brothers find their killer in a trance mumbling an ancient prayer.

However, I don't there are any mentions of "voodoo" *or* "hoodoo" in the [script](http://www.supernaturalwiki.com/8.03_Heartache_(transcript)), nor a death scene like the one you describe.